# How to Install Hugs Compiler in ubuntu?

Tags: haskell, hugs

I want to program in Haskel, a functional programming language and I want to install Hugs compiler for that in Ubuntu. Does anybody have any idea about it's installation.

Comment: Hugs is pretty much obsolete; it hasn't been maintained in years. Most people use GHCi instead.

Comment: Win Hugs was the windows version of Hugs, which wouldn't work on Ubuntu even if it weren't obsolete and unmaintained. Install GHC instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install hugs compiler in Ubuntu you just need to execute two under given commands.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hugs

To start working with hugs, type **hugs** in terminal and start working with it. Type **:?** for help. To terminate it, type **:quit**.